# Does not change the value of the variable $scope.data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with a values in $scope.data which does not change.
You can to see in jsfiddle - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkrychylskyy/8842yh49/)

If you set `Currency: 'UAH'` after you will set `Currency: 'RUB'` you will see the value of `Qty:2` will be equal to the value of `'UAH'` like this: `prix = {"qty":"2","amount":"1276 UAH"}`

How I can set the value to $scope.data?

P.S.: with AngularJs 1.2.23 it's work correct

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Umer said, you cannot use track by non unique values. So change the code as follows:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.qty for option in data.availableOptions track by option.amount"
ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
```

**Working Fiddle**:https://jsfiddle.net/8842yh49/2/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 'track by' on non unique values, because 'track by' requires a one-to-one mapping. Using 'qty' will not work as it is not unique as wty 1,2,3 and 4 map to different values for each prices object (not one-to-one). Add the following change and it should work.

```
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
    ng-options="option.qty for option in data.availableOptions track by option.qty"
    ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
```

Should be, ng-selected is so that when the currency is changed the first value will automatically be selected:

```
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
    ng-options="option.qty for option in data.availableOptions"
    ng-model="data.selectedOption" ng-selected="$first"></select>
```